# What do coeffcients mean from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-prediction

I ask for a brief explanation of each coefficient and their sources of related information. Thank you very much in advance.

The coefficients comes from this code below:

I've got a robust linear regression, (least absolute deviations)

[fttedSgnal,gof] = fit(mdfdTime((Conds(1,2):Conds(2,2))),fltdSignal(Conds(1,2):Conds(2,2)),...
    'poly1',robustOptions);

And the coefficients are here:
[image]

Comment: I don't know if these are coefficients or parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered reading the documentation ?
https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html

```
Goodness-of-fit statistics, returned as the gof structure including the fields in this table.

sse:         Sum of squares due to error
rsquare:     R-squared (coefficient of determination)
dfe:         Degrees of freedom in the error
adjrsquare:  Degree-of-freedom adjusted coefficient of determination
rmse:        Root mean squared error (standard error)
```

Comment: It's true, I was searching the documentation, but I got the function mixed up with another one by mistake. I ask for pardon. Thanks overall.